# Machine Learning Web Application error in Flask

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I am a newbie in machine learning model deployment and have been trying to deploy a simple machine learning model on car price prediction in Flask and Heroku. Have made the model using sklearn pipeline and transformer. The code runs perfectly on the Jupyter Notebook.
Deploying it in Heroku through Github, shows Build succeeded. However on launching the application, its shows application error.
It seems there something is wrong with the app.py file code for Flask. Any help or insight would be really helpful. Thank You

Jupyter Notebook Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

data = pd.read_csv('car data.csv')
data['current_year'] = 2020
data['car_age'] = data['current_year'] - data['Year']

num_features = [col for col in data.columns if data[col].dtype != 'O' and col != 'Selling_Price']
cat_features = [col for col in data.columns if data[col].dtype == 'O']

X= data.drop(['Selling_Price'], axis=1)
y = data['Selling_Price']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

num_transformer = Pipeline(steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler())])
cat_transformer = Pipeline(steps =[('OneHot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('numerical_transformer', num_transformer, num_features),
                                                ('categorical_transformer', cat_transformer, cat_features)])

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
rf = RandomForestRegressor()

grid_param = {'n_estimators' :[100, 200, 500, 800, 1000]}

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_grid= grid_param)

model = Pipeline(steps= [('preprocessor',preprocessor), ('grid_regressor', grid)])
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_predict = model.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error

MAE = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_predict)
MSE = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_predict)
RMSE = np.sqrt(MSE)

import pickle
file = open('regression_model.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(model, file)
```

Code for the app.py file for Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import jsonify
import pickle
import numpy as np
import sklearn

model = pickle.load(open('regression_model.pkl', 'rb'))   
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def Home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/predict", methods= ['POST']   
def predict(): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Year = int(request.form['Year'])
        Selling_Price = float(request.form['Selling_Price'])
        Present_Price = float(request.form['Present_Price'])
        Kms_Driven = int(request.form['Kms_Driven'])
        Owner = int(request.form['Owner'])
        car_age = 2020 - Year
        
        Fuel_Type_Petrol = request.form['Fuel_Type_Petrol']
        if(Fuel_Type_Petrol=='Petrol'):
                Fuel_Type_Petrol=1
                Fuel_Type_Diesel=0
        elif (Fuel_Type_Petrol =='Diesel'):
            Fuel_Type_Petrol=0
            Fuel_Type_Diesel=1
        else:
            Fuel_Type_Petrol=0
            Fuel_Type_Diesel=0
            
        Seller_Type_Individual = request.form['Seller_Type_Individual']
        if(Seller_Type_Individual =='Individual'):
            Seller_Type_Individual=1
        else:
            Seller_Type_Individual=0
            
            
        Transmission_Mannual=request.form['Transmission_Mannual']
        if(Transmission_Mannual=='Mannual'):
            Transmission_Mannual=1
        else:
            Transmission_Mannual=0
            
        data = [Selling_Price, Present_Price, Kms_Driven, Owner, Fuel_Type_Petrol, Fuel_Type_Diesel, Seller_Type_Individual, Transmission_Mannual, car_age]
                    
        prediction = model.predict([data])          
        output = round(prediction[0], 2)
        
        if output <0:
            return render_template('index.html', prediction_texts="Sorry you cannot sell this car")
        else:
            return render_template('index.html', prediction_texts= "You can sell the car at {}".format(output))
        
    else:
        render_template('index.html')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Could you provide the error code that you are receiving?

Comment: error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"

Comment: Not that, show the actual error. The stack overflow that you received

Comment: have you tried in cli run `heroku restart`? does it help?